# aurelia - setting up aurelia-validation results in module not found

Tags: aurelia

I had this same problem with aurelia-api and aurelia-authorisation in that I cannot seem to add these plugins without it not being recognised. In my login.ts file I have added:

```
import {ValidationRules, ValidationController} from "aurelia-validation";
```

...and its telling me it cannot find module aurelia-validation.

I recently asked [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050556/aurelia-setting-up-basic-authorization-pipeline-causes-navigation-links-to-dis) question and then followed the comment suggestion but still to no avail.

Had a look for similar questions but the one I did find was out of date.

This is what I have done.

Added "aurelia-validation" as a plugin in the boot.ts file as follows:

```
        import "isomorphic-fetch";
        import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";
        import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-fetch-client";
        import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
        import "bootstrap";
        declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build

        export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
        aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()
            .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"));  // Here!

        if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
            aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
        }

        new HttpClient().configure(config => {
            const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href;
            config.withBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        });

        aurelia
            .start()
            .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app/app/app")));
```

As you can see I have used:

```
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-validation"));
```

This was after adding "aurelia-validation" to the package.json file and then running yarn.

Do I also need to add this to webpack?

How do you add these plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your webpack is configured, you probably just need to add this to the vendor section of your webpack.config.vendor.js file as well, something like this:

```
module.exports = ({ prod } = {}) => {
    ...
    return [{
        ...,        
        entry: {
            vendor: [                            
                ...
                'aurelia-validation',
                ...
            ],
        },
        ...        
    }]
};
```

And then compile the vendor.js file as well if that is not done automatically in your build process using something like this:

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download npm install aurelia validation --save,and save it  in the same  folder or path of your project,if u are using IDE for your development check if it has a terminal or console, then type :npm install aurelia validation --save, i had a similar issue and this is how i reoslved it, good luck